# merge night and night-shooting tags?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-naming

[night](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/night) is not heavily used, but [night-shooting](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/night-shooting) is. I don't think there's much value in having both.

I kind of think that "shooting" is extraneous, and that it'd be better to merge [night-shooting](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/night-shooting) into [night](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/night). (And make it an alias for the future.) But, whichever, really.

Comment: As an aside, I love that [tag:tag-synonyms] is itself a synonym on meta here.

Comment: I'm okay with it. Have you voted to merge the tags?

Comment: JoanneC: I can't in the direction I want to, because night-shooting is the more popular one and it won't allow non-mods to do that.

Comment: Ah... Okay. I'll give it a bit of time to see if there's any objection (can't imagine it, but you never know) and then I'll do the merge. It makes sense to me.